# Is it possible to connect to specific queue and read specified number of messages?

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to create a maintenance tool, that should be able to modify messages in the queues. For example in _error queues. The idea is to read some specified count of messages from queue by its name. Store them to files. Modify the files. Than read them by the tool and publish to specified queue.

There are no problems with publishing.

```
var sendEndpoint = await _busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"rabbitmq://localhost/{sendEndpoint}")).ConfigureAwait(false);
await sendEndpoint.Send(message, messageType).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But I can't figure out how to read specified count of messages. I'm playing with this, but still have no idea how limit message count I want to read:

```
_busControl.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(endpointName, cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Handler<T>(context =>
            {
                // some handler logic
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
```

Thanx for the ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (using MassTransit) to read individual messages from a queue.

You would need to use the transport client library to read the message (including the headers and body) and write it to the file. That same tool could be used to send the message back to the broker.

RabbitMQ has a *shovel* feature for moving messages between queues, that might help. For Azure Service Bus, there is a ServiceBusExplorer project that has some useful message management tools.

Comment: Thanx Chris. Can I use transport client library from MassTransit.RabbitMQ nuget package? I know about **shovel**, but it has no message modification options.

Comment: You can use the RabbitMQ.Client library, which is what MassTransit.RabbitMQ uses.